# How to modify output in bash command pipeline

Tags: bash, pipe

For example, I got from some command some lines

```
$ some-command
John
Bob
Lucy
```

Now I'd like to add chaining command, that modifies output.

```
$ some-command | other-command
Hi John Bye
Hi Bob Bye
Hi Lucy Bye
```

How to write `other-command`? (I'm a novice in bash)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*awk*

```
$ some-command | awk '{print "Hi "$1" Bye"}'
```

*sed*

```
$ some-command | sed 's/\(.*\)/Hi \1 Bye/'
```

#### Examples

Using `awk`:

```
$ echo -e "John\nBob\nLucy" | awk '{print "Hi "$1" Bye"}'
Hi John Bye
Hi Bob Bye
Hi Lucy Bye
```

Using `sed`:

```
$ echo -e "John\nBob\nLucy" | sed 's/\(.*\)/Hi \1 Bye/'
Hi John Bye
Hi Bob Bye
Hi Lucy Bye
```

Comment: You forgot `some-command | paste -d\  <(printf '%s\n' Hi Hi Hi) - <(printf '%s\n' why Why WHY??)`

Comment: @kojiro - wasn't feeling the `paste` way today, thanks 8-)

Comment: For the `awk` solution, I'd say using `$0` is better in most cases than the currently suggested `$1` in order [to use a whole line rather than just a line's first (space-delimited) "argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15647452/923560). Example: `echo -e 'John Smith\nBob Miller\nLucy Doe' | awk '{print "Hi "$0" Bye"}'`

Answer (score 5):

The code below reads line after line, storing it in variable `LINE`. Inside the loop, each line is written back to the standard output, with the addition of "Hi" and "Bye"

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE ; do
   echo "Hi $LINE Bye"  
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Bash while loop and pipes :

```
echo -e "John\nBob\nLucy" | while read n; do echo "hi $n bye"; done
```